# T-test method of solving doubt

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

A machine fills bags of sugar and a random sample of 20 bags selected from a week's production yielded a mean weight of 499.8 g with S.D = 0.63 g. A week later a sample of 25 bags yielded a mean weight of 500.2 g with S.D = 0.48 g. Perform a test to determine whether the mean has increased significantly during the second week.

This was pretty straightforward: I took the pooled S.D = 0.56440. Calculated t-value  2.36. Turns out mean has increased

The second part of the question states: Test whether the mean during the second week could be 500 g. This is where I actually stumbled. Tried the same pooled s.d t-test formula - doesn't work. Then realised, probably, I don't need to take pooled S.D, I should do simple t-test with only the second week's mean and S.D?

Comment: Your first answer is wrong, you need a two-sample t test, no pooling.

Comment: @user2974951 did the two sample t-test only (with common population variance).

Comment: The second part seems like using the data n = 25, mean = 500.2, and SD = 0.48 to perform a one-sample t-test. Basically, compute the 95%CI for week two, and determine if the number 500 is included within the interval. If yes, don't reject the null of "population mean = 500", and if excluded, do the opposite by rejecting the null.

Comment: The first question is problematic due to rounding.  It is possible that the first mean actually is 499.84 g and the second is 500.16, in which case you would *not* conclude there's a significant difference (with 95% confidence)!  You might find it interesting to evaluate the second question in the same way.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight ok, that's what I meant in the last sentence.

Comment: [a] I would have done a Welch (separate-variances) 2-sample t test for the first part. (if the mean can change in a week, maybe so can the variance.) [b] A one-sample procedure seems appropriate for the second part. For CI, I get $(500.01, 500.39),$ which technically does not contain 500, but  original data is rounded to one or two places, it does seem a borderline decision (as Commented by @whuber). A 96% CI touches 500; and, of course, the lower limit of a 94% CI is farther away.